# Converting subquery with SUM and many WHEREs to Join structure for performance

Tags: mysql, performance

Can I obtain the same result in a more efficient way?

Below query is fast for few records, but I have a huge performance problem with more than 100 results and already large `tasks` table.

I wanted to redo it to a JOIN struct, but with no luck so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    `t`.*,
    (
        SELECT SUM(`tasks_sub`.`delivered`) 
        FROM `tasks` AS `tasks_sub`
        WHERE ((`tasks_sub`.`table` = `t`.`table` AND `tasks_sub`.`proces_id` = `t`.`proces_id`)
            OR (`tasks_sub`.`order_id` = `t`.`order_id`))
            AND `tasks_sub`.`index` = `t`.`index`
    ) AS `sum_delivered`
FROM 
    `tasks` AS `t`
```

Table `tasks` structure:

```
Tasks
`id`, `table`, `proces_id`, `index`, `delivered`
```

Comment: For each task, I need to count total delivered amout for the same `index` in other tasks (inclusing current one) across (`order_id` **OR** (`table` AND `proces_id`)).

Comment: Does this modification to your where clause give the same results ((`tasks_sub`.`table` = `t`.`table` AND `tasks_sub`.`proces_id` = `t`.`proces_id`)
            OR (`tasks_sub`.`order_id` = `t`.`order_id`))
            AND `tasks_sub`.`index` = `t`.`index` ?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question for clarity. The business logic is OK. The problem is with query performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this rewrite

```
SELECT t.*,
    (   SELECT  SUM(ts.`delivered`)
            FROM  `tasks` AS ts
            WHERE  ts.`table` = `t`.`table`
              AND  ts.`proces_id` = `t`.`proces_id`
              AND  ts.`index` = `t`.`index` 
    ) +
    (   SELECT  SUM(ts.`delivered`)
            FROM  `tasks` AS ts
            WHERE  ts.`order_id` = `t`.`order_id`
              AND  ts.`index` = `t`.`index` 
    ) AS delivered
FROM tasks AS t
```

Together with two new indexes:

```
tasks:  INDEX(table, proces_id, index,  delivered)
tasks:  INDEX(order_id, index,  delivered)
```

Comment: I added some `IFNULL`s and (without adding indexes yet) that is like 100x faster... why?
I was thinking about redoing it to JOINS, but Your solutuion made it work.
Thank You!

Comment: @MichałMoskal - `OR` usually leads to reading every row in the table.  Your original `JOIN` read all of one row, then all of the other (same) table.  The covering indexes lets it allow my query to read _part_ of each of two indexes.  (That's the short explanation; the long one involves explaining several nuances of indexes in MySQL.)

Comment: Thank you for help!